# where to host my Java web app to fully decentralised?

Tags: java, decentralization, p2p

I need a idea to host my webapp to be on some secure distributed network. my client doesn't want to deployed on aws or gcp. he wants it to be on decentralised network p2p. Your suggestion and advice will be great to figure the right technology and network for this app.Thanks already.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's not related to Ethereum. P.S. I don't think you can have decentralized website currently, such infrastructure simply doesn't exist. But I might be wrong.

Comment: How about hosting it on IPFS?

Comment: IPFS is just a storage system like aws s3 bucket. we cannot run tomcat server on that.

Comment: @Curious.BCoder You do not mention anything about tomecat or any other framework you use. This question is unclear and not suitable for this site.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain tomcat is just an example as java web app needs container to run. i had clearly mention java web app can you please help with any solution to host it decentralised.